# How to delete data that has foreign key in jpa java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have use case, a Book has one Category and a Category could belong to a lot of Books. One Book could belong to multi Authors and an Author could belong to multi books. So, here is their relationship:

1. `Book` to `BookCategory` => `many-to-one`
2. `BookCategory` to `Book` => `one-to-many`
3. `Book` to `Author` and `Author` to `Book` => `many-to-many`

So, I have 4 table:

1. `book`
2. `book_category`
3. `author`
4. `book_author` (`book_id`, `author_id`)

Case:

1. if I delete a `Book`, there should nothing happen to the `book_category` table
2. If I delete a `Book`, the `Author` should be deleted if the `Author` not belong to any `books` anymore. For example, I have `book1` and `book2` with same `Author` named `John`. If I delete `book1`, it wont delete `John`. But if I delete `book2` also, then `John` will be deleted from `Author` table. Also, any book deletion will affect `book_author` table.

here is how I declare the entity

**Author**

```
@Entity(name = "author")
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false)
    private String address;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Book> book;
}
```

**Book**

```
@Entity(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private String year;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
      name = "book_author",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Author> author;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) 
    private BookCategory category;
}
```

**Book Category**

```
@Entity(name = "book_category")
public class BookCategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "category", nullable = false)
    private String category;
}
```

and here is how I try to delete the book. Just a simple method. But, after I run this, it show error said `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "book_category" violates foreign key constraint "fk5jgwecmfn1vyn9jtld3o64v4x" on table "book"`, which seems like the method try to also delete the `book_category` table.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) throws Exception {
        try {
            bookService.deleteById(id);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("delete done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Then, how to achieve it? Any clue, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in the category field in Book class.
Using `CascadeType.ALL`, whenever you try to delete a Book, its category must be deleted too. The problem is that it might exist other books instances with the category you want to delete in your database. Then, a constraint database error will be thrown.

So, I would recommend using `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` or `cascade = CascadeType.MERGE` in the category field. In this way, when you delete a book, the category will not be deleted.

This [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/) will give you a better understanding of cascade types, showing how it works.

I tend to avoid using cascades, especially `CascadeType.ALL` and `CascadeType.REMOVE`. I prefer to make several calls to the persistence layer in order to perform some business task (similar to those at the beginning of your question in the enumerated items - if I delete a book ..). Besides, Spring allows you to put all calls in a transaction using `@Transactional` in any method of your business layer.

Comment: yeah, thats work man. I change `CascadeType` to `PERSIST` on every column that need to define the `CascadeType`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Thiago. When I change to persist, it work for the category. But, when I check it again, turns out that the author table not affected with book deletion. Did u know what might be wrong?

Comment: The book_author data will be deleted, the author data will not. As in my answer, your business rules seem to be complex. That's why I recommend you to make calls to your persistence layer like: bookService.deleteById(idBook) and authorService.deleteById(idAuthor)

Comment: yep, the `book_author` is deleted. Maybe, when doing deletion, I could do check to `book` table whether deleted author still belong to any other books or not. If not then I'll do `authorService.deleteById(idAuthor)`. Thanks a lot!